# WPF UserControl - Binding parent window as command parameter to ContextMenu MenuItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, menuitem, commandparameter

I have a `UserControl` with `Button` inside which opens a `ContextMenu` when left clicked. I'm trying to  pass `UserControl`'s parent `Window` as a parameter to `ContextMenu` item's command to close that window, but with no avail. I've tried everything with `RelativeSource` and `PlacementTarget`, but parameter is always null. I'm aware that `ContextMenu` is not part of parent window's `VisualTree`. I'm currently stuck with this approach, but it is not working.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="0" 
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="120" 
            Height="25" 
            Content="Dashboard Menu" 
            TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" 
            Foreground="AliceBlue"             
            >

            <!--Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={ x:Type Window}}}"-->
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                    <MenuItem Header="Open Log Viewer" Command="{StaticResource openLogViewer}" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{StaticResource exit}" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Command is a Referenced command defined in `UserControl.Resources`:

```
<my:CommandReference x:Key="exit" Command="{Binding Exit}" />
```

and it's Execute part is triggered but parameter is always null. So, my question is, what is the right way to bind parent window as `CommandParameter` of `MenuItem`. Any help is appreciated, because this thing is bothering me for almost two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way here is to **not** pass parent `Window` to the VM as `CommandParameter`. If this is MVVM you should be using a Messenger(MVVM Light) / EventAggregator(Prism) approach to send a Message to the `Window`'s code-behind when the command is triggered to Close it.

Referencing `Window` in the VM is just plain wrong.

Just for reference, what your trying to do "can be done"

something like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="0" 
          Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="120" 
          Height="25" 
          Content="Dashboard Menu" 
          TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" 
          Foreground="AliceBlue"
          Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Open Log Viewer" Command="{StaticResource openLogViewer}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Command="{StaticResource exit}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag,
                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                  Header="Exit" />
...
```

**Update:**

[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxinxy7mc6lvexh/MvvmLight16.rar)

When executing the "Exit" command from the `ContextMenu` you should see `Sender Object: MvvmLight16.MainWindow` in your Output Window. This output is sent from the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but this is the first approach that I tried and it doesn't work. I know that I'm breaking MVVM pattern when I'm passing parent window to VM, but I'm not using any of the MVVM toolkits.

Comment: @wannjanjic I've updated my answer with a download link to a sample that uses the approach I said and it works fine for me. Well if you're not using any MVVM toolkit's maybe your should consider using one than break MVVM. Rather might as well not use MVVM tbh.

Comment: @wannjanjic oh and delete `DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` from your `ContextMenu`. Not sure why you even needed that

Comment: Thanks for the sample solution. It is working fine for me also, but when I use the same approach in my project it doesn't work at all (parameter is still null). Maybe there's difference because my button is inside UserControl which is placed on MainWindow (Parent).

Comment: @wannjanjic That makes no difference, Just tried it to confirm as well. I'd guess to start debugging switch your command from `CommandReference` to a simple command like you had in my example and see if it works fine. I'd guess the command parameter is set correctly however the Command does not use it being a `StaticResource`

Comment: @wannjanjic Just tried it with a `CommandReference`[Josh Smith's version](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit) and it still works fine. Sorry not gonna be of much help without knowing what's going on in your code. You should get [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and check `DataContext` from `Button` -> `ContextMenu` -> `MenuItem` on the sample i gave you and your project and see where they differ

Comment: It doesn't work for me at all. I tried to pass `"10"` as `CommandParameter` and it worked. I don't know what is preventing me to pass parent window. Anyway, thank you very much for your time. I'll mark your answer as accepted, because your solution works fine.